# Best way to switch click events to touchstart with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch

I have a web application which uses lots of `$(document).on('click', selector, ...)` event handlers and I'd like to switch all of them to 'touchstart' event instead, but I want to avoid any event bubbling or duplication in any case.

I was thinking to separate all of this into seperate JS files but, there are lots of these files utilizing the event listener mentioned above.

I'm interested in any programmatical way to achive this, if any?

I was thinking of:

```
$('a, button, input').each(function() {
    $(this).on('touchstart', this.click);
});
```

But it might be a performance issue.

Comment: try with both events $(this).on('click touchstart', this.click); if the device does not have click event it will trigger touchstart or vice versa

Comment: As I said, I don't want duplication of any sort. I want to force touchstart on mobile devices, click on desktop browsers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe it's a solution for you to decide which event to use based on what kind of events are implemented in the device used. My approach basically is:

```js
var clickEvent;

if ('onpointerdown' in window) {
    // use 'pointerdown' if pointerEvent API is supported
    clickEvent = 'pointerdown';
    console.log('pointerEvents used');
} else if ('ontouchstart' in window) {
    // use 'touchstart' if touch device
    clickEvent = 'touchstart';
    console.log('touch device');
} else {
    // else use mouse event
    clickEvent = 'click';
    console.log('old fashioned mouse events');
}

$(document).on(clickEvent, '#testbtn', function(e) {
    $(e.target).css('color', 'red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="testbtn"> Testbutton </button>
```

Works very well for me.