# Is ("ontouchstart" in window) legit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, touch, device

I'm trying to detect whether my website is viewed through a touch device. If so, it shall disable my "mouseenter" and "mouseleave" bindings.

Therefore the condition ("ontouchstart" in window) is used. But I'm actually not sure about the browser support and reliability of this condition. Does anyone have some up-to-date information or even an alternative to detect touch support?

---

The code snippet:

```
if(!("ontouchstart" in window)){
    $('.slider-wrapper').on({
        mouseenter: function() {
            isPause = true;
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
            isPause = false;
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Should be good from IE11 and up, IE10 used `msMaxTouchPoints`

Comment: It absolutely is if you don't need support for Browsers < IE11. You might also want to have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40743177/best-way-to-switch-click-events-to-touchstart-with-jquery/40744084#40744084